# Filter domains without path and http/https with grep

Tags: bash, grep, filtering

i wonder how can i filter just domains (without protocol:// and /path). Example i need something like this: `echo "Hi it's my web site (https://1stsubdomain.2ndsubdomain.example.com/welcome/)" | grep "some regex"`

I want get this output: `Hi it's my web site (1stsubdomain.2ndsubdomain.example.com)`

And domain can be with 3 subdomains or just 1 or without

Extensions i want: `.com|net|org|ru|xyz|co|tr|uk|vn|intedu|mil|lnc|is|dev|travel|info|biz|email|build|agency|zone|bid|condos|dating|events|maiso|partners|properties|productions|social|reviews|techgov|au`

Comment: What did you try up to now?

Answer (score 0):

Use `-o` to print only the matched (non-empty) parts
Please make sure to include all top-level domains you want

```
echo "Hi it's my web site (https://1stsubdomain.2ndsubdomain.example.com/welcome/)" | grep -Eo '[A-Za-z0-9_\.-]*\.(com|net|org)'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but output is false. Output: n.example.com

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` if applicable

```
$ echo "Hi it's my web site (https://1stsubdomain.2ndsubdomain.example.bid/welcome)" \
| sed -En 's#https://(.*\.)(com|net|org|ru|xyz|co|tr|uk|vn|intedu|mil|lnc|is|dev|travel|info|biz|email|build|agency|zone|bid|condos|dating|events|maiso|partners|properties|productions|social|reviews|techgov|au)[^)]*/?#\1\2#p' input_file
Hi it's my web site (1stsubdomain.2ndsubdomain.example.bid)
```

Comment: If last character is not be / it's not work, code: echo "https://www.example.com" \  
| sed -En 's#https://(.*\.)(com|net|org|ru|xyz|co|tr|uk|vn|intedu|mil|lnc|is|dev|travel|info|biz|email|build|agency|zone|bid|condos|dating|events|maiso|partners|properties|productions|social|reviews|techgov|au).*/#\1\2#p'     output: nothing

Comment: still not work                                                                                                          ┌──(rootUgroon)-[/]
└─# echo "https://1stsubdomain.2ndsubdomain.example.bid" \ 
| sed -En 's#https://(.*\.)(com|net|org|ru|xyz|co|tr|uk|vn|intedu|mil|lnc|is|dev|travel|info|biz|email|build|agency|zone|bid|condos|dating|events|maiso|partners|properties|productions|social|reviews|techgov|au).*/?(\))#\1\2\3#p'
                                                                                                                              ┌──(rootUgroon)-[/]
└─#

Comment: Output: still nothing  
@HatLess

Comment: You can check too. If path is empty or last char is not / it's not work

Comment: Still not work. Screen Shot: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/905154478133641269/916002198054404197/unknown.png?width=1260&height=273

Comment: @Ugroon Sorry, I have been stuck in a meeting. Give me a moment and check edit